# Отсутствует кнопка форматирования кода в мобильной версии сайта

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, мобильная-версия, форматирование, редактор

По мотивам ситуации с этим вопросом: [Есть ли возможность сделать код практичнее и короче?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/897091/%D0%95%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5)

Суть такова: участник заходит на сайт через мобильную версию сайта (допустим, с телефона), пишет вопрос, вставляет код из стороннего редактора. Т.к. код должным боразом не отформатирован, получает соответствующую плашку:

[image: Плашка]

При этом он не может ни нажать ctrl-k (т.к. пишет с телефона), ни нажать упомянутую кнопку на панели инструментов, т.к. этой кнопки в мобильной версии сайта, внезапно, нет:

[Мобильная версия с телефона](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyIhZ.png)

[Мобильная версия с компьютера](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXk3j.png)

Очевидное решение участника: воспользоваться имеющейся кнопкой и вставить код картинкой (что, очевидно, хуже чем неотформатированный код), на что в ответ получает негодование и призывы ознакомиться с правилами.

Что интересно, если на телефоне перейти на полную версию сайта, то редактор там будет со всеми необходимыми кнопками на панели инструментов:

[Полная версия с телефона](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqhey.png)

Мое мнение: раз уж сайт в полной версии вполне пристойно выглядит с мобильных устройств, то по-умолчанию на мобильных устройствах должна показываться полная версия сайта.

Comment: Адаптивный дизайн в частности для того и пилят, чтобы мобильную версию упразднить.

Comment: А вообще, форматировать код можно и пробелами.